# Using Imported DataSet to fill DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datasource

In my WindowForm project I have imported my SQL Server Database using the *Add New Data Source wizard*. So, in my project I have now a DataSet and a TableAdapter for each table in  my Database.

The question is how do I use these imported objects to fill my datagridview?

In the example here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource?view=netframework-4.8) it seems they are creating a new objects (not using existing object that I imported).

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you opened up, in the Designer, the ComboBox selector of the DataSource property of your DataGridView?

Answer (score 0):

This is it what do you mean? Sorry of using of MySQL but it's similar to SQL

```
string conn = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;CharSet=utf8mb4;";
                string query = "SELECT * FROM project1.workers";


                connection = new MySqlConnection(conn);
                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection);


                ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds, "workers");
                datagrdvPracownicy.DataSource = ds.Tables["workers"];

connection.Close();
```